# Fourier transformation of experimental data into frequency domain

Tags: python, fft

I'm totally new to python. I have conducted a wave data test experiment. I have the time series data available with me. How do I proceed to show that in a frequency domain? Is there any examples I can refer to? I came up with a program as given below but it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
#Program for Fourier Transformation
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readdat( filename ):
    """
        Reads sectional area curve data from file filename
    """

    # read all lines of input files
    fp = open( filename, 'r')
    lines = fp.readlines() # to read the tabulated data
    fp.close()

    # interpret data
    time = []
    ampl = []
    for line in lines:
        if line[0:1] == '#':
            continue # ignore comments in the file
        try:
            time.append(float(line.split()[0])) #first column is time
            ampl.append(float(line.split()[1])) # second column is corresponding amplitude
        except:
            # if the data interpretation fails..
            continue
    return np.asarray(time), np.asarray(ampl)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    time, ampl = readdat( 'data.dat')
    print time
    print ampl

spectrum = fft.fft(ampl)
freq = fft.fftfreq(len(spectrum))
print freq
```

Comment: Are you sampling data at a regular time interval?

Comment: yes. I'm using a time step of 1/100 sec

Comment: "(my program) doesn't seem to work". What doesn't work? What were you expecting to happen? What happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

Minimal correction of your program to have some result plotted is something like this

```
#Program for Fourier Transformation
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readdat( filename ):
    """
        Reads sectional area curve data from file filename
    """

    # read all lines of input files
    fp = open( filename, 'r')
    lines = fp.readlines() # to read the tabulated data
    fp.close()

    # interpret data
    time = []
    ampl = []
    for line in lines:
        if line[0:1] == '#':
            continue # ignore comments in the file
        try:
            time.append(float(line.split()[0])) #first column is time
            ampl.append(float(line.split()[1])) # second column is corresponding amplitude
        except:
            # if the data interpretation fails..
            continue
    return np.asarray(time), np.asarray(ampl)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    time, ampl = readdat( 'data.dat')
    print time
    print ampl

spectrum = fft.fft(ampl)
timestep = time[1]-time[0] # assume samples at regular intervals
freq = fft.fftfreq(len(spectrum),d=timestep)
freq=fft.fftshift(freq)
spectrum = fft.fftshift(spectrum)
plt.figure(0,figsize=(5.0*1.21,5.0))
plt.plot(freq,spectrum)
print freq
plt.xlabel("frequencies")
plt.ylabel("spectrum")
plt.savefig("/tmp/figure.png")
```

Comment: I get an error as given below Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "C:\Users\ajanardh\Documents\Fourier.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbookFile "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 15, in <module>
    import new

Comment: File "C:/Users/ajanardh/Documents\new.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 20, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
ImportError: cannot import name interactive